# why margins collapse effect background images?

Tags: css, background, margin

I have simple HTML and CSS as following. I notice the bottom margin collapse between .outside box and .inside box. **I don't understand why i can't see the background image when bottom margin collapse,** background image should nothing about margin.
Thanks :)

```
<div class="outside"> 
<div class="inside"> content </div>
</div>


.outside {background:url(http://blurfun.com/temp/images/bottom.png) left bottom no-repeat;    padding-top:1px;}

.inside { background:#00CCFF; margin:0 0 10px 0; padding:0 0 20px 0;}
```

Comment: use `background-image` instead `background`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experimenting vertical margin collapse between your nested divs
Include this overflow property (any value not equal to visible will do the job), and it will work ok

```
    .outside {
       background:#ff0000 url(http://blurfun.com/temp/images/bottom.png) left bottom        no-repeat;    
padding-top:1px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

The red color was added only to test the result. Of course you can wiped.

**Detailed comment**

Your outside div uses a sort of yellow strip at its left bottom.

Your inside div has a bottom margin of 10 px and as there is nothing in between this margin and the outside div bottom margin. Thats why they are collapsing.

You could prevent this to happen including a bottom padding or even a bottom border to outside div. But this would change your design intentions.

That is why I suggested using the overflow property which also prevents the vertical margin collapse and does not interfere with your design.

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/sYjSQ/) I added a left margin to the inside div and a red background to the outside div.

For didactic porpouse I also included a transparent background to the inside div.

**Vertical Margins collapsing**

[image: Vertical Margins collapsing]

**Prevented by overflow:hidden**

[image: Prevented by overflow:hidden]

Play with it. Delete the overflow property and watch vertical margins collapsing.
I hope is clear enough for you.

Have a good day and enjoy your coding :-)

Comment: Hy. I have just extended the answer in reply to your comment. I included a jsFiddle as well.